# Can I automate my XML layout creation for various screen resolutions in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

[image]

This picture essentially says it all. What I've always done is manually create different layout types for various devices and screen resolutions from a single initial layout file, reformatting while I mercilessly copy and paste until my thumbs get soar, i.e. default, -sw480dp, -large, -xlarge, etc. depending on the needs of my app. For example, adding support for -sw480dp through -sw720dp has allowed some of my friends with much older phones to open my apps without some kind of NullPointerException that prevents them from even using it at all. However, this is extraordinarily tedious sometimes, especially when making a change in one layout file that you want to also show up in every other version. Bottom line is that more supported devices means more positive reviews, and fewer redundant negative reviews for your apps over time.

So my problem now is that I want to support all these layouts for the highlighted layout shown in the screenshot provided, but I really don't want to do what I did for `comment_listview_item` all over again.

I've never worked in a design agency with colleagues who are full-time Android developers, and I've yet to come across a good tutorial about this subject. As far as I know, whatever process might conceivably automate what I want to accomplish here is a mystery.

Is there something that I can do that by starting with the highlighted layout in the screenshot provided will automate the process of creating new layout files in the fashion of those below it? I refuse to believe that this process genuinely involves all the copy-paste and reformatting that I'm currently engrossed in. Cheers.

Comment: Do you really need all these variants? What's the difference between them?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know and that's what I'm trying to figure out. v21 for example supports elevation for toolbars, whereas v16 supports the sans-serif-light font, and the default layout file supports neither. I find it preferable to have each of those for each defined screen resolution, but maybe there's a quicker, more automated way to achieve the same thing? Adding support for -sw480dp through 720dp also seemed to fix my friend's inability to even open the app because of his old phone. The Android documentation is great but what are designers actually doing, I wonder.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to create all those xml file for every layout. Interestingly Android automatically adjust the screen size according to the device. But if the screen is too small or the resolution is too low then your xml contents may not appear correctly in such devices. For precision in your work , you can simply create layout for small,  large and extra large screen. You might need to create another xml if you want to adjust landscape mode as well . This link will help you out : https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

Answer (score 1):

I've found that creating 4 versions of a layout for each broad size category (small, medium, large, x-large) and allowing the Android system to handle the rest doesn't really work across the board.

In addition to using weights - nested weights shouldn't become a performance issue if you're using 2 to 3 layers - you can dynamically scale your fragments and view components by using percentages of device screen width and height fetched at runtime. I'll post a code example later.